# Java : Questions on clone method

Tags: java, clone, effective-java

I am reading Effective Java and the book has the below comment on the clone method.

> In practice,
>   a class that implements Cloneable is expected to provide a properly
>   functioning public clone method. **It is not, in general, possible to do so unless
>   all of the class’s superclasses provide a well-behaved clone implementation,
>   whether public or protected.**

Can anyone give examples of why this can't be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine one of the base classes has a private field that to be copied in a specific way for a "clone" to be semantically valid.

If that base class does not provide a correct clone implementation, the derived class can't either - it has no way of building that private field correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if part of your class hierarchy includes a class that is not under your control and not part of the JDK (ie. a 3rd party closed-source class), and this class does not implement a well-behaved `clone()` method, then it's not going to be particularly easy to produce one.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases a class is usually written with clone not implemented. So when a child class is written it is likewise written with clone not implmented. At some point it is required to write a clone method in a child class but it's parents don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

```
`@override
public MyClass clone(){

Myclass clonedObj = super.clone(); // This is why the classtree all needs to be cloneable

// now copy values of all members to the new obj.
// be carefull to not copy references
clonedobj.setMyMember(this.getMyMember()); // copy of member var;
clonedobj.setMyotherMember(this.getMyOtherMember().clone()); // a composit obj must be cloned.

}
`
```

this can be the anwser?